# How to remove specific url link from input field

Tags: jquery, url, input

I have search form with specific action

```
<form method="get" action="info.php?short=" id="urlcreateform">
<input id="urlbox" name="short" placeholder="Some text" type="text">
```

Visitors of my site will use this form to find some stats, but they will past or write to input field full url link such as (http:/example.com/123456).
And that's problem. I now how to remove http from input field, but I cant find answer how to remove url address such as http:/example.com/ from input field.

Does anybody now how to do it? I can't find nothing.

Comment: Is this always the same url? Or can it differ?

Comment: So, you want to match URLs, and if it's a URL, forbid it? (Like, for security reasons?)

Comment: Its the same url. Only numbers after slash will be different.

Comment: @JeremyThille I think to clarify, he wants people to paste URLs in for simplicity, but the specific information his code needs is everything after the `com/` portion. YouTube video links that need to be processed into an ID might be a good example.

Comment: Do you wanna remove it while writing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
var urlNumbers = $("#urlbox").val().replace("example.com/", "");
```

If you want to be safe and also remove any possible `http://` or `www.` then use the following regex:

```
var urlNumbers = $("#urlbox").val().replace(/example.com\/|http:\/\/|www./gi, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your URL always looks like 'http:/example.com/123456' then you can just substring it at the last "/".

In Javascript, you can detect the last "/" and split it like this:

```
var originalUrl = $("#urlbox").val();
var urlNumbers = originalUrl.substring(originalUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

However, it is better to do this on the PHP side (and work more securely with POST instead of GET):

```
$originalUrl = $_POST["short"];
$urlNumbers = substr($originalUrl, strrpos($originalUrl, "/"));
```

Documentation:

- [Javascript substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)
- [Javascript lastIndexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)
- [PHP substr](http://php.net/substr)
- [PHP strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP was looking for a solution in Javascript / jQuery, not PHP.

Comment: This is actual result when i submit my form. /info.php?short=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F123456  All what I need is tha the result should be /info.php?short=?123456  I will try to google it again. But thanks for respons.

Comment: Its not clear in what language the OP wants it, but the solution would work the same way in JavaScript or PHP, they both have LastIndexOf and Substring methods.

Comment: @DarinMorris I have expanded your answer with code examples and solutions in both languages. I hope that's alright.

Comment: Thanks, was just doing that! :)

Comment: Here is a working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/w7vaxmqc, which uses JavaScript to split the URL up as desired.